# How to montor WP7 HTTP traffic when connected via USB cable

Tags: windows-phone-7, fiddler

Im using Fiddler2 to monitor HTTP traffic from a Windows Phone 7 app, by proxying the phone's wifi connection to the PC running Fiddler2. Works like a charm. However, this only works when the phone is not connected via the USB cable. Obviously this is not acceptable as you can't debug the phone app this way.

How do you achieve the same with the phone connected via the USB cable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone team decided to host their debug bridge on port 8888, stealing all traffic that was intended to be sent to Fiddler.

You can fix this in Fiddler by clicking Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections to move Fiddler to a different port (e.g. 8887).

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/-Ja4L_tezOc